# Where to find Chunk of Adamantine?

Tags: darksiders-3

After finishing my first playthrough of the game, I was wondering where to find **Chunk of Adamantine**. I believe that it should be possible to obtain it in the base game, but couldn't find one so far.

So my question is, where can I find Chunk of Adamantine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based from [here](https://gameranx.com/features/id/166089/article/darksiders-3-all-chunks-of-adamantine-locations-fully-upgraded-weapons-guide/):

> - **Adamantine Chunk #1**: Haven, North End – Face the church from the Serpent Hole and turn left. Run to the giant root and grapple to the root on the opposite side.
>
>   - Use the Fire Hollow and grapple-swing across two more roots to reach a lonely balcony. There’s a free Level Up (Luminous Visage) on this balcony.
>   - Swing again from this balcony, then turn the corner and enter the building. Use the Force Hollow to break through the barrier. You’ll find the Chunk down the stairs inside.
> - **Adamantine Chunk #2**: Bonelands, Cargo Ship – Cross the acid pool area nearby with the Storm Hollow. On the other side, go left and around to the back of the building with the squid jump-pad. Go to the back-corner of that building and wall-jump up the shaft with the Stasis Hollow.
>
>   - Up here, swap to the Force Hollow and roll across the magnetic surface. At the end, jump across the floating containers in the acid lake and reach the small island with the chunk.
> - **Adamantine Chunk #3**: Scar – Go up the conveyor belt section in Scar using the Stasis Hollow and reach the moving platforms you can ride. Ride to the end and drop down to the grinders. Use Stasis to freeze the grinders, and slide down. There’s a human collectible on this path.
>
>   - The last Chunk of Adamantine is located down here.

Comment: With the release of "The Crucible" DLC, it is possible to buy an infinite amount of "Chunk of Adamantine"